# Running Behat tests from Jenkins

Tags: php, jenkins, behat

I'm trying to run some Behat (3.0.15) tests from Jenkins but Behat is raising some failed steps.

For example for this step:

```
And I should click the header "Cómo Funciona" link
```

The error:

```
And I should click the header "C??mo funciona" link # test_behavior/Resources/features/Web/StaticPages/como_funciona.feature:9
     [exec]       "clickCMoFuncionaLink" method is not available on the Header (BadMethodCallException)
```

Our build.xml

```
<target name="behat">
    <exec executable="vendor/bin/behat" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="--tags=~@skip"/>
        <arg value="--profile=jenkins"/>
        <arg value="--format=progress"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

And our behat.yml

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      paths: [%paths.base%/test_behavior/Resources/features/Web]
      contexts:
        - TestBehavior\Context\BaseContext
    service:
      paths: [%paths.base%/test_behavior/Resources/features/Services]
      contexts:
        - TestBehavior\Context\BaseContext
        - TestBehavior\Context\ServiceContext:
          - http://xxxx
    command:
      paths: [%paths.base%/test_behavior/Resources/features/Commands]
      contexts:
        - TestBehavior\Context\BaseContext:
          - false
        - TestBehavior\Context\CommandContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://xxxxx:8080
      browser_name: chrome
      selenium2:
        wd_host: 10.0.2.2:4444/wd/hub
      show_cmd: open -a Google\ Chrome %s
    SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension:
      namespaces:
        page: [TestBehavior\Object\Page]
        element: [TestBehavior\Object\Element]

jenkins:
  suites:
    default:
      env: integration
    service:
      env: integration
      contexts:
        - TestBehavior\Context\BaseContext:
          - false
        - TestBehavior\Context\ServiceContext:
          - http://xxxxxx
    command:
      env: integration
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://xxxxx
      selenium2:
        wd_host: 10.52.2.84:4444/wd/hub
```

Locally everything works fine

Comment: Can you post the ant command, or whatever script you use to run behat?

Comment: @gvf question updated

Comment: Looks like an encoding error, it's "translating" the header text to `C??mo funciona`, so it can't seem to process the `ó`. Try setting the locale to UTF-8 at the beginning of your Jenkins script: `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;export LANG=en_US.UTF-8;export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`, that should process those letters properly.